# How NodeJS middlewares works?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware

My question is why `console.log("after middleware")` is printing only once while `app.use(foo)` is calling after every page reload. Does using NodeJS code is interpreted one time after use `npm start` in console despite page reload?

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

function foo(req, res, next) {
    console.log("middleware1")
    next()
}

app.use(foo)
console.log("after middleware");

app.get('/', function(req,res){
    res.send("main page")
})

app.listen(3000)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, to simplify it a little, `app.use()` is a listener, that is called every time the page is visited. The `console.log()` on the other hand is regular code that is called only once, when your code is run.

Answer (score 0):

A middleware is a function that return a function.
Example:

```
function myCustomMiddleware(x) {
   
  return function (req, res, next) {
    // This returned function can access to 'x' variable
    console.log(x)
    next() // Continue to the controller function.        
  }
}

app.get('/', myCustomMiddleware("Hello"), function(req,res){
  res.send("main page")
})
```